# Alexa schedule a skill set

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

Can I schedule a developed skill in Alexa. 
For example, I have written some code to do an operation(skill) and that has to be triggered on any scheduled time.

Thanks

Comment: Should Alexa respond you back after some time? Or you want to give her a command and it should be executed after sometime on a remote server?

Comment: Alexa should respond. As an example, my daily youtube views count should be responded twice a day.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As for today it is not possible for Alexa just to say something back after some time.

But that you can do is to take a look at [Notifications](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-voice-service/notifications-overview.html). Then your users can check pilled messages once they have time.

Or you can try [Alerts](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-voice-service/alerts-overview.html) functionality if users should take an action immediately. Think of it as a timer which starts beeping once it is about time.

Comment: You're pointing to AVS functionality and he's asking about ASK (alexa-skills-kit tag). They don't have the same features. You need to take a look at this again for ASK

Answer (score 0):

Alexa cannot be activated by an external trigger, which means, it will respond only if the user initiates the conversation. But ALexa does provide Notifications and Reminders access to custom skills. Basically there are 2 ways to get an update on your YouTube view count, but none of them are ideal.

1. Reminders

You can add the Reminders functionality to your custom skill, so that it will remind you everyday at a certain time. But it will always preface the conversation with 'Here is your reminder.'

2. [Notify Me - Alexa Skill](http://www.thomptronics.com/notify-me)

This is an Alexa skill that once you enable, will give you a URL. You can use the URL on a service like IFTTT with webhooks and have it send you notifications. This will show up as a yellow ring on your Alexa device. But, Alexa will not read it out to you unless you ask 'Alexa, what are my notifications?'